# Library to convert Span<char> to native type in .net standard 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am aware .net core 3 and .net standard 2.1 supports this out of the box but I'd need to convert Span of characters to native type (double, int etc). Unfortunately I can't use the latest and greatest as .net framework does not support .net standard 2.1.

Is there any extension method that helps optimize and convert for .net std 2.0?

Comment: I guess you can do int.Parse(mySpan.ToString()) in case int.Parse does not have parse method that support span<char>

Comment: sorry but that defeats the purpose you suggestion would allocates object on the heap, i am doing this on a hot path and need optimization as we have in .net core where it rent from the pool instead of allocating object on the heap.

Comment: @RohitSharma if you want .NET Core features and performance you'll have to upgrade to .NET Core. You'll have to do so anyway, and the LTS version, .NET Core 3.1, already has a Go Live license, ie it's supported in production

Comment: Yes unfortunately our vendor Bloomberg whose library we use has not decide to upgrade to .net standard

Answer (score 0):

`int` does provide methods overload for parsing `Span<char>` and `ReadOnlySpan<Char>`

```cs
Span<char> mySpan = new char[] { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' };
var myInt = int.Parse(mySpan); //myInt = 123465
var parsedPassed = int.TryParse(mySpan,out var myInt2); //myInt = 123465
```

I am using `netcoreapp2.2` and i have enabled `LangVersion` `7.2` here is how my csproj looks like

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>7.2</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Yes i am aware of this as i mentioned in the question, i am looking for compatibility with .net standard 2.0 not netcoreapp